# pg_dump with ssl certificates

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.1, pg-dump

I would like to run the pg_dump command from a remote host off my database server that only allows fully verified certificate based connections. How should I go about doing this? The man pages for 9.1 state the instructions for connecting via password from what I could see.

Comment: Do you mean *client certificates*? If so, it's the same as for `psql`, put them in `~/.postgres`

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
pg_dump "port=<port> host=<host> user=<user> dbname=<db> sslcert=<cert> sslkey=<key> sslrootcert=<ca.crt> sslmode=verify-ca" -f <file>
```